# handle undefined window in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a constant file which I share between my node backend and frontend (.ts file)

In backend inside the file I have done something like this

```
if (window) {
   window.redirectPaths = { 
   // some code
   }
} else {
// something
```

}

For NodeJS, Since window doesn't exist, I thought it will go to else but instead it is throwing the following error

```
if (window) {
^
ReferenceError: window is not defined
```

Any help in why is this happening and how can I solve this?

Answer (score 3):

use **typeof window !== "undefined"**

```
if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
   window.redirectPaths = { 
   // some code
   }
} else {
//
```

Answer (score 2):

you want to check the window type first before accessing it.

```
if (typeof window === 'undefined'){

 // some code
} else {
   window.redirectPaths = { 
   // some other code
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check this way

```
if (typeof window !== 'undefined' && window){
 window.redirectPaths = { 
   // some other code
   }
} else {
   // some code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Node.js environment it is called `global` object. So you can write `global` instead of `window`

Answer (score 1):

you could use try catch

```
try {
   window.redirectPaths = {
     // some code
   }
} catch (err) {
   // something else
}
```